# CentOS bond networking can't work after reboot

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, bonding

I create a NIC bond with two NICs with mode 6 in Cent OS 6.5. This is the configuration file:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.8
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
MTU=1500
BONDING_OPTS="mode=6 miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=1"
```

However, after reboot, I can't see bond0. Then I view the bond configuration file again, I find the last line disappears:

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0 
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.8.81
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
MTU=1500
```

I add this line and restart, then the bond NIC can work.

```
BONDING_OPTS="mode=6 miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=1"
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with it? I don't change the file manually when the problem occurs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the problem persistent or happened just once?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is NetworkManager issue, it's remove `BONDING_OPTS` from configuration file. There is two ways to fix this issue, first one to add `NM_CONTROLLED=no` in configuration file and try to restart. Second one, to create new file in `/etc/modprobe.d/bond0.conf` and put there:

```
alias bond0 bonding
options bonding mode=6 miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=1
```

This file wouldn't be overwritten after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Add `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to your configuration files and enable the 'network' service at startup.

```
chkconfig network on
```

Then disable the NetworkManager service.

```
/bin/systemctl disable NetworkManager.service
```

Restart your machine.